# Python pyserial and runaway CPU usage

Tags: python, pyserial

MacOS 10.7.3, python 2.5

I am using pyserial to open a connection to an external server. The connection is opened as:

```
HOST = '10.0.0.1'
PORT = '16010'
theURL = 'socket://' + HOST + ':' + PORT
conn = serial.serial_for_url(theURL, baudrate=115200)
conn.timeout = 2
```

and then the read looks like this:

```
try:
    while len(rawData) == 0 and self.shutdown == False:
        rawData = conn.readline()
except:
    some error handling code...
```

The problem is, if I kill the server at 10.0.0.1:16010 the code keeps running, but the cpu usage goes to 100%. No error is thrown, so the except is never entered.

This looks like a problem in pyserial, but maybe someone here has run into this before and knows how to detect the lost connection so the situation can be handled gracefully.

Thanks.

Comment: Readline is desirable for this application since the incoming records are of various lengths, but all are \n terminated. If the only way to catch the error is to read character at a time and build the string that way, I guess it could work... but it seems like unnecessary work. However, the problem is that no exception is thrown, so, error trapping does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not depending on `.readline()` you could do it like this:

```
self.plugin.conn = Serial(..., timeout = 1)
...
if not self.shutdown:
    rawData = self.plugin.conn.read(1)
    if rawData:
        rawData += self.plugin.conn.read(self.plugin.conn.inWaiting())
    else:
        raise Exception("timeout")
```

I'm not sure if I got your intent right so you might have to adjust...

Comment: I tested this approach, but still get the same result. No error is thrown

Comment: Ah, sure I forget to mention that you have to set a read timeout: `Serial(..., timeout=1)`

Comment: It looks like there is some problem in pyserial or the underlying socket module. But, pyserial is definitely not reporting an error when the far end quits. I will file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your CPU usage is pegged probably indicates the the readline call is not blocking to timeout but returns instantly.  So if your normal timeout
is 2, you could use:

```
from time import time

try:
    while len(rawData) == 0 and self.shutdown == False:
        before = time()  
        rawData = conn.readline()
        if (len(rawData)==0) and ((time()-before)<2):
              raise Exception("Early readline return.")
except:
    some error handling code...
```

Answer (score 0):

A very good solution to this can be found [here](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/216#issuecomment-369414522):

```
class ReadLine:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.buf = bytearray()
        self.s = s

    def readline(self):
        i = self.buf.find(b"\n")
        if i >= 0:
            r = self.buf[:i+1]
            self.buf = self.buf[i+1:]
            return r
        while True:
            i = max(1, min(2048, self.s.in_waiting))
            data = self.s.read(i)
            i = data.find(b"\n")
            if i >= 0:
                r = self.buf + data[:i+1]
                self.buf[0:] = data[i+1:]
                return r
            else:
                self.buf.extend(data)

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)
rl = ReadLine(ser)

while True:

    print(rl.readline())
```